# Issue while compare and sum digits of two numbers

Tags: java

So, the thing is that I have two lines with two numbers on each line. On each line the numbers are separated by space. What I'm trying to do is to compare which number is bigger on the line and sum digits of the bigger number.

Example

```
1000 2000
2000 1000
```

In this case the output should be

```
2
2
```

because on the first line the right numbers is bigger and the sum of it digits is 2. The second line is the opposite.

What I have so far is this

```
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        String numbers = scanner.nextLine();

        String[] parts = numbers.split(" ");
        double leftNumber = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
        double rightNumber = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

        if ( leftNumber > rightNumber ) {
            while (leftNumber > 0) {
                sum = (int) (sum + leftNumber % 10);
                leftNumber = leftNumber / 10;
            }
        } else {
            while (rightNumber > 0) {
                sum = (int) (sum + rightNumber % 10);
                rightNumber = rightNumber / 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Result that I've get is

```
2
4
```

it is adding the second line result to the first one. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You need to reset the `sum` value, since `sum` is used only inside for-loop, put `int sum = 0;` in for-loop

Comment: Why are you using `double`? Suppose you keep dividing by 10, at a certain point you'll get `2`, you divide it by 10 and get 0.2, which is still > 0. At best you'll waste cycles.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I'm very beginner in this and still learning. Why I use double here is because when it was `int` and I put number like `99999999999999`  I get error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "99999999999999"`

Comment: @JasonWung you could check `BigInteger`... (note when you use `double` you *will* lose precision and the result might be wrong!)

Comment: @JasonWung ask yourself whether that's a valid input to begin with (i.e. does the exercise text explicitly ask for it?) because while `double` can indeed represent that kind of value it's not really the best type to represent integers, even just because it communicates to whoever reads that code that you expect a number with decimals. You should probably check `BigInteger` (which comes with its own complications about doing simple algebraic manipulations) or you should accept that you can't accept *every* input a user gives you (and treat that exception appropriately).

Comment: I hear you about the double issue and BigInteger. What I though is that later I cast it to `int` again and this is okay in my case - here in the `while` `(int) (sum + leftNumber % 10);`

Comment: But yes, when I debug got that decimal.. 2000-> 200-> 20-> 2-> 0.2-> 0.02 ... and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make things easier on yourself and just treat the integers as strings for the purpose of summing the digits?

```
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        int larger = Math.max(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
        String sLarger = String.valueOf(larger);
        int digitsSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sLarger.length(); i++) {
            digitsSum += sLarger.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        System.out.printf("Larger number %s sums to %d%n", sLarger, digitsSum);
    }
```